# Underscore in gets and sets in symfony entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, twig

In my entity, i've got a field with underscore in variable name, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $value_text;
```

And, for example, a get function:

```
public function getValueText()
{
    return $this->value_dec;
}
```

With that, symfony is throwing an exception:

```
Neither the property "value_text" nor one of the methods "value_text()", "getvalue_text()"/"isvalue_text()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\MyEntity".
```

So I've changed the function name, added the underscore, but then when i want to add a row, symfony is throwing same error, but in the other way - it's ignoring the underscore, and looking for function like getValueText().

Why that's happening? I've made two functions doing same thing, my code works, but ofcourse i think there is a better way to do this, without doubling the function.

Comment: Better using camelCase for variable name

https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use this:

```
public function getValue_dec() {
    return $this->value_dec;
}
```

But the convention is to use camel case so It's better this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
 */
private $valueDec;

public function getValueDec()
{
    return $this->valueDec;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Symfony uses camelCase for property naming conventions.

Here is official doc for [Naming Conventions](https://symfony.com/doc/current/contributing/code/standards.html#naming-conventions)

Read more related articles

[[PropertyInfo] Implement Naming Strategy for Properties](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/16889)

[Added support for non-camel-case variable code conventions #29](https://github.com/doctrine/collections/pull/29)